# In a Netbeans java project: How can I copy misc. data files into build directory

Tags: netbeans

After a build of a java applet I would like to copy a file, or files from $PROJECT_DIR\data into the build directory. Can I do this easily somehow by marking the files in some way, or must I write an ant copy statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant build.xml is the way to go, IMO.

Comment: Any clues?

I managed to make it work if I Run -> Build project. But when right right click and "run" the applet, the files dissapear. It appears -compile-single doesn't call -post-compile

<target name="-post-compile">
        <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}/data">
            <fileset dir="data"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

Comment: what's "post compile"?  Just add the copy command to your packaging target.  Sounds like you're being too clever with Ant.

Comment: `<copy file="filetocopy" todir="../myfolder"/>` – maybe use nbbuild.xml instead of build.xml

Comment: The question is 13 years old.  Better to find newer questions.